# How to prove that a 3x3 matrix, with unknowns, is invertible?

Tags: matrices

I have  the following question:

Let A be a 3x3 matrix and $$P=\left(\begin{matrix}u&v&w \end{matrix}\right)$$

be a 3 x 3 matrix where $u$, $v$, $w$ are columns of P

such that
$$ Au = au, Av = bv, Aw = cw $$ for some real numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Show that if P is invertible, then $$A = P\left(
    \begin{matrix}
      a&0&0\\
      0&b&0\\
      0&0&c\\
    \end{matrix}
\right)P^1$$.

What I do know is that $u$, $v$ and $w$ are 3x1 matrices. Hence, when $A * u$, I'd end up with a 3x1 matrix and since $Au$ = $au$, it shows that the $(i,1)$-entry of $A$ is a scalar multiplication of $u$. This process can then be used to show that $(i,2)$ and $(i,3)$-entry of A are scalar multiplication of $v$ and $w$ respectively.

However, I could not proceed from here not knowing how to show that $P$ is invertible.

I have tried the following but I am not sure if I am even right in the first place:

Since $Au = au, Av = bv, Aw = cw$, this shows that $u$, $v$ and $w$ are nonzero columns. Therefore, $P$ is not singular and hence, is invertible.

Comment: I interpret "Show that if P is invertible, then..." that you are allowed to assume that P is invertible.

Comment: As Olba says: you're not supposed to *show* that $P$ is invertible, they're telling you that $P$ is invertible.